# Initialize first entries of an array of objects in class constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer

If I have class A that declares Class B and instantiates an array of it.

```
class A{
    class B{
        int x, y;
    };
    B arrB[10];

 public:
    A();
};
```

Then, my issue is that I would like to initialize the first two objects of "arrB" in Class A using initialization list:

```
A::A(): arrB[0](1, 2), arrB[1](3, 4) {}
```

But the compiler does not accept it.

Can I initialize specific objects of the array or not? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you need this in the initialization list instead of just in the constructor function body?

Comment: Maybe something like: `arrB{{1,2},{3,4},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}` or `arrB{{1,2},{3,4}}` however rest of the elements gets random values and it must be a struct or public x,y

Comment: @KIIV: The second form is fine; the rest of the elements will be zero initialized

Comment: The compiler complains on the second form as it gives  error asking about init of the rest of the array items

Comment: After the edits in question it won't work. It'll work with  `struct { int x, y; };`

Comment: Please don't edit the code significantly after answers have been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `B` hides its members by default as `private` because it is a `class`. Declare `B` a struct, or expose `int x, y` as `public` to be able to use aggregate initialization:

```
class A{
    class B{
        public:
        int x, y;
    };
    B arrB[10] = {{1,2}};

 public:
    A();
};
```

The second problem is that you're not using aggregate initialization properly.

```
A::A(): arrB[0](1, 2), arrB[1](3, 4) {}
```

Should be

```
A::A(): arrB{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} {}
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5z7z55TVxDH1mXno)

Answer (score 1):

In order to initialize an array in the class member initialization list you need to use curly braces like you would if you were initializing an array in a function.

Thus if you wanted to initialize the first and second element of the array you would need to use at least

```
A() : arrB{{1,2}, {3,4}} {}
```

as the first set (`{1,2}`) says make `arrB[0]` a B with `x` and `y` initialized to `1` and `2` respectively. The second set (`{3,4}`) says make `arrB[1]` a B with `x` and `y` initialized to `3` and `4` respectively.

You do have to do one thing though in order to make this work.  You either need to make `B` and aggregate by making `x` and `y` public, or you can provide a constructor for `B` that takes to values.  Doing that lets you have either

```
class A{
    class B{
    public:
        int x, y;
    };
    B arrB[10];

 public:
    A() : arrB{{}, {3,4}} {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

or

```
class A{
    class B{
        int x, y;
    public:
        B() : x(), y() {} // need this so default instances are value initialized (zeroed in this case)
        B(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    };
    B arrB[10];

 public:
    A() : arrB{{}, {3,4}} {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```